# Mostrar datos de un arreglo en JSF

Tags: jsf

Quisiera saber como puedo solucionar mi problema y es que al momento de darle al botón que se supone que esta vinculado al método de añadir no se si esta añadiendo y cuando pruebo a mostrar los datos "agregados" anteriormente no muestra ninguno de los datos y redirecciona a la pagina index sin ningún cambio.

```js
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Nombres</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:inputText value="#{datos.nombres}" maxlength="100"></h:inputText><br></br>
            <h:commandButton value="Añadir" action="#{listaNombres.añadirNombres()}"></h:commandButton>
            <h:commandButton value="Mostrar" action="#{listaNombres.mostrarNombres()}"></h:commandButton><br/>
            <h:outputLabel>Nombres Ingresados</h:outputLabel><br/>
            <h:outputLabel>#{listaNombres.mostrarNombres()}</h:outputLabel>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>



/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

/**
 *
 * @author Karlos PC
 */
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class datos {

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of datos
     */
private String nombres;    
    public datos() {
    }

    /**
     * @return the nombres
     */
    public String getNombres() {
        return nombres;
    }

    /**
     * @param nombres the nombres to set
     */
    public void setNombres(String nombres) {
        this.nombres = nombres;
    }
    
}



/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

/**
 *
 * @author Karlos PC
 */
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class listaNombres {

ArrayList<datos> array=new ArrayList();

    public listaNombres() {
    }
    public void añadirNombres(){
       datos x=new datos();
       array.add(x);
    }
    public void mostrarNombres(){
        
       for(int i = 0; i <array.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        
        
        }
    }
```

Como se puede ver intento que el cambio de texto sea el valor agregado en el arreglo y que al momento de leerlos con el ciclo For simplemente recorra y me vaya mostrando cada indice, pero no muestra nada como anteriormente dije.

Comment: Uno de los inconvenientes que veo es que estas usando un scope de tipo request . Eso mantiene los valores vivos durante una única petición http . Podrías cambiar a view scoped .

Answer (score 0):

Uno de los problemas que veo es que usas un request scoped. Eso mantiene los valores del bean vivos en una única petición.  Podrías cambiar a view scoped . Otra cosa que veo es que debes actualizar el componente outputlabel cada vez que añades un nuevo elemento a la lista . Es mejor si utilizas ui:repeat para iterar y mostrar los valores de tu lista o un datatable .